# Use AppServiceAuthentication with signalR

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, signalr

I'm trying to build a notification mechanism in my backend app (azure mobile app).
I managed to override the Authorize attribute in order to make the notification hub accessible only for authorized users.

```
public class QueryStringBearerAuthorizeAttribute : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {

        try
        {
            var user = (request.Environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            if (user == null)
                return false;
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        var connectionId = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.ConnectionId;
        // check the authenticated user principal from environment
        var environment = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request.Environment;
        var principal = environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // create a new HubCallerContext instance with the principal generated from token
            // and replace the current context so that in hubs we can retrieve current user identity
            hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context = new HubCallerContext(new ServerRequest(environment), connectionId);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the startup.cs file :

```
 var authorizer = new Hubs.QueryStringBearerAuthorizeAttribute();

 var module = new AuthorizeModule(authorizer, authorizer);
 GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(module);
 app.MapSignalR();
```

From a console app (c#) I'm able to connect to the notification hub by providing the X-ZUMO-AUTH header. However, from a web application, It's not possible to set the header.

Is there a way to use the query string to check the authentication token instead of the header?

Comment: what do you mean with web application ? A browser website ?

Comment: yes I mean a website

Comment: Do you use XHR or [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: xhr,
here is how I connect to signalR hub :
 $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('token', 'value');
            }
        });

$.connection.hub.url = 'http://myUrl/signalr';
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
//stuff
}

however the header is not properly set, on server side it's not being received

Comment: Did you try the answer ? I looked around, and for the ZUMO Auth you need the Header: 'X-ZUMO-APPLICATION' and add you Application Key as Value.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to explain it quite well: https://forums.asp.net/t/2121061.aspx?How+to+disallow+connections+in+signalr

In `AuthorizeHubConnection()`, use `request.QueryString.Get("token")`

In `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation()`, use `hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.QueryString.Get("token")`

Answer (score -1):

To add an XHR Header you can use

```
var url = "www.example-mobile-azure-app.com";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-ZUMO-APPLICATION', 'Application-Key');
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function () {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
        // do what you need to do
    } else {
        // oh no an error occurred -.-
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: this doesn't work since I'm not making an ordinary http request, I' just invoking the connect function of signalR framework, which apparantly doesn't allow setting request headers, thank you anyway.